# Query to send post request in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create a Calorie Info API which saves calorie intake for a user.

- If it is a new user, then add an entry for the user id and item id.
- If the user already exists,

  - If the item is new, then just map the item id and the calorie count with that user.
  - If the item id is already mapped with that user, then add the items calorie count with that item for that user.

    ```
    Url: /api/calorie-info/save/
    Method: POST,
    Input: 
         {
             "user_id": 1,
             "calorie_info": [{
                    "itemId": 10,
                    "calorie_count": 100
             }, {
              "itemId": 11,
              "calorie_count": 100
             }]
         }

    Output: 
       - Response Code: 201
    ```

My model:

```
class CalorieInfo(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    itemId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    calorie_count = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried:

```
class Calorie(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        user_id = data['user_id']

        for i in data['calorie_info']:
            entry = CalorieInfo(user_id=user_id, item_id=i['itemId'], calorie=i['calorie_count'])
            entry.save()

        res = {"status": "success"}
        return Response(res, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The above code works fine but how can I check the above conditions in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check like this:

```
def post(self, request):

    data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    user_id = data['user_id']

    # fetch calorieinfo object for given user
    user_calorieinfo = CalorieInfo.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
    # if user exists
    if user_calorieinfo:
        # ifCalorieInfo item mapped with user
        for i in data['calorie_info']:
            if CalorieInfo.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,itemId=i['itemId']:
               for obj in CalorieInfo.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,itemId=i['itemId']):
                   updated_count = obj.calorie_count + i['calorie_count'] 
               CalorieInfo.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,itemId=i['itemId']).update(calorie_count= updated_count)            
            else:
                entry = CalorieInfo(user_id=user_id, item_id=i['itemId'], calorie=i['calorie_count'])
                entry.save()
    else:
        for i in data['calorie_info']:
            entry = CalorieInfo(user_id=user_id, item_id=i['itemId'], calorie=i['calorie_count'])
            entry.save()

    res = {"status": "success"}
    return Response(res, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Hope this will work!

```
#for getting CalorieInfo object
def get(self):
    id = request.GET.get('user_id')
    user_calorieinfo = CalorieInfo.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
    response["user_id"] = id
    response["calorie_info"] = []
    for obj in user_calorieinfo:
        response["calorie_info"].append({"itemId":obj.itemID, "calorie_count":obj.calorie_count})
    response["status"] = success
    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209552/discussion-on-answer-by-meha-parekh-query-to-send-post-request-in-django).

Comment: @code_nation just removed the loop in the updated answer!

Comment: Do you know how to get data in similar manner if i'm trying to get data for an id let say 1 and I get the response in same manner ? @MehaParekh

Comment: yes, you can pass the id and filter object of it and you need to set a dict because by default it will not return as you expect! If you wish I can add it to the answer! @code_nation

Comment: yes please, Thanks a lot.and the above code can't add any other itemId it works perfect for 1st time but if i change the ids and send it again it doesn't work. @MehaParekh

Comment: @code_nation Updated the answer! and for the second time which error did, you got?

Comment: yaa, so we need to update our calorie count by adding previous calorie count remember ? @MehaParekh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209565/discussion-between-code-nation-and-meha-parekh).

Answer (score 0):

If user and item are representing an entity then you should have separate table for this. Those table should be used as foreign key in this table.

For user, Django already have `auth.User` model. So you do not have to create a seperate table for this

For item, you can define a table like this

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Your table will become like this

```
class CalorieInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to='auth.User')
    item = models.ForeignKey(to='Item')
    calorie_count = models.IntegerField()
```

No need to write foreign keys like `user_id` or `item_id` as Django do it automatically to the foreign key. When will user foreign keys, Django will make sure if these objects which are referred with foreign keys already exist in database.

Your view will look like this

```
class CalorieView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        data = request.data
        for ci in data.get('calorie_info', []):
            clinfo, created = CalorieInfo.objects.update_or_create(
                user_id=data.get('user_id'),
                item=ci.get('itemId'),
                defaults={'calorie_count': ci.get('calorie_count')
            )
        return Response(
              {"status": "success"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: What will be the query to get the data in same format for a particular id let's say user_id = 1? @Muhammad Hassan

Comment: `CalorieInfo.objects.filter(user_id=1)`